# Necessity to consider the square of Four Momentum

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, momentum, inertial-frames, scattering

Why do we often need to consider the square of four momentum transfer $Q$ in scattering experiment or particle physics/cosmology instead of just the $Q$ itself?

Comment: If physical quantities were to depend on components of $Q$, the theory wouldn’t have relativistic invariance.

Comment: Do you mean why not get the length of the four-vector momentum transfer, i.e. the square root  of it? the way we use m and not  $m^2$  ?

Answer (score 6):

The four-momentum of a physical system is a conserved quantity in a particular reference frame. But we need a relativistic invariant theory which doesn't depend on the  choice of coordinates. The squared four-momentum is a [scalar invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_scalar), i.e., it doesn't depend on any reference frame. Thus a relativistic invariant theory requires a formulation based on invariant quantities.

Comment: I think the question is why $q^2$ instead of $\sqrt{q^2}$. Both are Lorentz invariant.